# Proper way to add a lot of event listeners

Tags: javascript

I often add a bunch of event listeners to things in my sites — a header menu, a sidebar menu, some buttons, some toggles, etc. By the end of a project, there could be a whole bunch of event listeners operating on a page.

I always do this sort of thing:

```
// all of our menu items
var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.primary-nav a');

// loop over them
_.each (menuItems, function(item){
    // add event listener to each
    item.addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log(item);
    });
});
```

So, on a given site, I might have 4-5 of those kinds of blocks.  Is it better to have all these listeners out there, or is it better to listen on the document and employ some kind of class/attribute filtering?

Like so:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if ( e.target.closest('li').classList.contains('primary-nav') ) {
        // We have a primary nav item, do something with it
    }

    if ( e.target.closest('li').classList.contains('mobile-menu-toggle')) {
        // function for toggling open the mobile menu
    }
});
```

Advice very welcome!

Comment: All comes down to performance impact. Either take the hit when it is rendering to add events directly or take a hit at having to filter events when they happen.

Comment: Just checking: you're not using jQuery?

Comment: `closest()` has limited browser support. Would need polyfill for it also

Comment: In jQuery can be done with one line $('.primary-nav a').click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click called." );
});

Comment: @derloopkat there is no jQuery being used in question

Comment: It's preference. For small projects I just add each listener individually. For bigger projects I use one click handler on the window and put a data-event attribute on each clickable element which hands off the event name to a mediator or other event handler that contacts the right module, if it exists.

Comment: no jQuery in sight, yeah. And I've left out all the polyfilling stuff. Got all that covered.

Comment: Why not use event delegation? That way you only add one event listener.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Your first example is more performant and only does what you ask it to, in a very clean way. The second example (as others said, it's incomplete - there is no "closest" method) can be more effective if you expect the DOM's structure to change, but don't want to be re-adding event listeners.

If you expect to add a new `primary-nav` or `mobile-menu-toggle`, then having the one root listener will mean no listeners have to change even when adding/removing elements. Frameworks like JQuery allow for this sort of thing with syntax like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.primary-nav', () => {
  ..
});
```

Similarly, the listener is added to `body`, but only responds to `.primary-nav` selector matchers. Keep in mind you should only use this when it makes sense based on the dynamic nature of a page; otherwise the "click" listener will get pretty complicated on a big page.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Just trying to point out that multiple frameworks have this feature, so it might be one reason to pick a framework instead of writing out the full javascript. If you want, you can take the answer as-is before even bringing up that code sample. (It's common to focus on an answer's code and ignore its text)